# Unable to get value from session in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-cookies, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello i have been struggling with this from past few hours still i can't find out where wrong goes.

I am setting the `session` with `user_id` in `SessionsController` like this

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

 skip_before_action :authenticate, except: [:logout]

def new
  @session = Session.new
end

def create
 @user_session = Session.new(session_params)

 if @user_session.valid?
   session[:user_id] = @user_session.user_id
   redirect_to learners_url
 else
   redirect_to learner_new_registrations
 end
end

def logout
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url
end

private

 def session_params
  params.require(:session).permit(:email, :password)
 end
```

end

in `create` action after setting session value it is redirecting to `learners_url`, but again it is redirecting to root url. observe the following `server log`

```
Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-13 12:00:01 +0530
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"session"=>{"email"=>"narasimha@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "login-submit"=>"Submit"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | project_practice_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"email"=>"narasimha@gmail.com"}, "limit"=>-1}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | project_practice_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000360343s
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/learners
Completed 302 Found in 67ms


Started GET "/learners" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-13 12:00:01 +0530
Processing by LearnersController#index as HTML
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | project_practice_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>nil}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | project_practice_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000387588s
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :authenticate rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-13 12:00:01 +0530
Processing by WelcomesController#about as HTML
  Rendered welcomes/about.html.erb within layouts/welcomes (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 15.4ms)
```

It means it is redirecting to `LearnersController#Index` Action. In `ApplicationController` i have set a `call back` like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery

  before_action :authenticate

  def authenticate
    return if signed_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id].to_s) #Problem is here. Here i am unable to access session[:user_id] which i was set in sessions controller. so it is redirecting to `root_url`
    rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound => ex
  end

  def signed_in?
    current_user.present?
  end

  helper_method :authenticate?
end
```

Help me to solve it. why i couldn't able use `session[:user_id]` values in application controller? Thanks in advance.
Note: I am using rails 5.0.0.beta3 version

Answer (score 0):

You never created session, try this:

```
def create
 #@user_session = Session.create(session_params)
 user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
   session[:user_id] = user.id
   redirect_to learners_url
 else
   redirect_to learner_new_registrations
 end
end
```

Since, you have not authenticated user. So in your `ApplicationController`, you have a method named `authenticate`. It first checks whether user is `signed_in?` or not. If not, then it redirects you to the `root_url`.

```
def authenticate
  return if signed_in?
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Comment: this is what i did in `SessionsController#Create` Action. what is the diffrence? @dkp

Comment: In `def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id].to_s)#puts session[:user_id] giving me nil after i authenticated user. 
    rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound => ex
  end`

Comment: `session[:user_id] = @user_session.user_id` - you have this statement in your create action. You should be getting the user from DB like `@user = User.find_by_email(params[]):email`. Then you can authenticate the user and set the session like `session[:user_id] = @user.id`

Comment: i have debug that by putting put statements in that. i am getting `@user_session.user_id` value from db successfully . even i am setting that value to session also. still it not working @dkp